# How can I use Canvas to show plots of user defined dimensions

Tags: android

All the examples of Canvas drawing that I have seen use

```
    public class CustomView extends View { etc.
```

In this class the drawing is carried out in the onDraw method using hard coded values. My app calculates geometric properties of shapes for user defined dimensions, displays them and offers the user the option to see a scale drawing of the shape from a 'View' button which starts a plotting activity that takes the shape and its dimensions as a bundle and then plots the drawing.
I am stuck trying to find a way to do the plotting from the plotting activity. The CustomView route doesn't work as the dimensions are hard coded.
Is there a way to pass the shape and dimensions to CustomView or should I be using a different method to plot onto a 'normal' activity view?